# OpenID which URL to use?

Tags: openid

I'm seeing multiple URLs returned by authenticating with Google

```
LightOpenID Object
(
    [returnUrl] =&gt; http://ikeyless/account/login/
    [required] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

    [optional] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

    [verify_perr] =&gt; 
    [capath] =&gt; 
    [identity:LightOpenID:private] =&gt; 
    [claimed_id:LightOpenID:private] =&gt; https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=[RANDOM_STRING]
    [server:protected] =&gt; https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
    [version:protected] =&gt; 2
    [trustRoot:protected] =&gt; http://ikeyless
    [aliases:protected] =&gt; 
    [identifier_select:protected] =&gt; 
    [ax:protected] =&gt; 1
    [sreg:protected] =&gt; 
    [data:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
            [openid_identifier] =&gt; https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
            [cmd] =&gt; account
            [act] =&gt; login
            [openid_ns] =&gt; http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
            [openid_mode] =&gt; id_res
            [openid_op_endpoint] =&gt; https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
            [openid_response_nonce] =&gt; 2010-11-16T16:49:30ZREDpfCsz7bwPsg
            [openid_return_to] =&gt; http://ikeyless/account/login/
            [openid_assoc_handle] =&gt; [RANDOM_STRING]
            [openid_signed] =&gt; op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle
            [openid_sig] =&gt; [RANDOM_STRING]
            [openid_identity] =&gt; https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=[RANDOM_STRING]
            [openid_claimed_id] =&gt; https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=[RANDOM_STRING]
        )
```

Which should I store locally and compare to when validating an OpenID user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=[RANDOM_STRING]

Comment: There are two keys that map to that URL: `openid_identity` and `openid_claimed_id`. Is the URL pointed to by `openid_identity` always identical to the one pointed to by `openid_claimed_id`?

Comment: If I understand [the documentation](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#identifying), the `openid_claimed_id` key is the one to use. From the docs: *The Claimed Identifier in a successful authentication response SHOULD be used by the Relying Party as a key for local storage of information about the user.*

Comment: And, to answer my own question: The `openid_identity` might actually differ from the `openid_claimed_id`. `openid_identity` is some *OP-Local Identifier:
An alternate Identifier for an end user that is local to a particular OP and thus not necessarily under the end user's control.*, says [the OpenID 2.0 spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html).